# WinForm closes even after removing Close()

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I'm encountering strange behaviour from my WinForms app in VS 2010. I launch a new form using straight-forward code:

MainDisplayForm.cs:

```
using (MyForm myForm = new MyForm())
{
    var result = myForm.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I added a Cancel button to MyForm that displayed a confirmation `MessageBox` to the user and then called `this.Close()`. I later *removed* the `this.Close()` line because I added a dedicated Close button. However, whenever I press Cancel the instance of MyForm still closes!

MyForm.cs:

```
private void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show( ... )
    // clear the form if user really wants to quit

    // this.Close()
    // even after removing the above line, program still jumps to FormClosing
}
```

When I debug line-by-line after clicking on the Cancel button, the program flow just jumps to `MyForm_FormClosing` after it hits the end of `cmdCancel_Click`. I created a new button and set its click event to `cmdCancel_Click` and it did not close the form - so the problem is **solved**, but I am still wondering if this is just a bug, or something else? I also made sure to reset the `DialogResult` property of my Cancel button back to `None` (after changing it to `Cancel` before I introduced the dedicated Close button).

Comment: did you by any chance set the cancelbutton property of the form to cmdCancel?

Comment: What is the DialogResult property value for the button?

Comment: @terrybozzio I got rid of that as well. I have another button, Save, which experiences the same problem. Both had `this.Close()`, and both continue to close the form even after I removed it.

Comment: @hatchet `DialogResult` is set to `None`

Comment: Is MyForm.CancelButton set to the Cancel button? You may need to change this value to the new Close button.

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right file? If you clicked 'Save As...', and made a new file with the same code. Then you'd still refer to the old form?

Answer (score 1):

When exiting the scope of 'using' statement, it calls 'myForm.Dispose()' (that's the whole point of 'using' - to make sure Dispose()is called). This in turn destroys 'myForm' instance, including closing the window.

Comment: yes your right of course but inside the using statement the form is shown modaly and as to wait for the dialog result,which in this case OP removed close() inside the button handler giving no indication to the form to close.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, or perhaps I worded it ambiguously. `cmdCancel_click` is a method within MyForm. When it finishes it calls `MyForm_FormClosing`, which closes the form and returns to the `using` statement which I have in my first code listing. My question is why it calls `MyForm_FormClosing` at all. This all happens before exiting the scope of the `using` statement. I've updated my code to hopefully be a bit clearer.